# django model return unique values

Tags: django, unique, models

I have two classes in my models:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    block_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Flat(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    flat_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

It gives me for example blocks with following names:

```
block1
block2
block3
```

and flats with following names:

```
pink_flat FK to block1
red_flat FK to block2
yellow_flat FK to block3
pink_flat FK to block2
pink_flat FK to block3
```

Question:

What function should I create in Block class so I can return all Flat unique names e.g. for above example I would like to return `pink_flat, red_flat, yellow_flat` and skip the fact pink_flat occurs more than once.

So, basically I would like to return unique flat_names for each Block

I know I can create function in my Block class so I can filter Flats:

```
def flats_related(self):
        return Flat.objects.filter(block=self.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`.distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
Flat.objects.order_by('flat_name').distinct('flat_name')
```

**EDIT: **
 Above code will work only for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @AKS - Oh yeah, forgot that. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For each block 
`block.flat_set().all()` should give you all the flats of that block. Then you can leave only the unique ones using `distinct()`. All together:
`block.flat_set().all().distinct('flat_name')`

You can read about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward